# How to pass values in a query string as values of the variable

Tags: python, html

Hey guys I have a question regarding query strings :

I am working on a web development framework using django and python.
The problem is trivial tell me if u know how to get around it

I have a string say str1= "Hello World"

now I need to pass this as a value to my query string

for example

< a href = "/graph?x=str1" >

so this query string should look something like this

/graph?x=Hello World

as in the value of the str1 should come in place in the query string.

However I get

/graph?x=str1

which I dont need and does not make sense.

Do u know how to extract the value of a parameter and substitute it in a query string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/string.html?highlight=string%20format#string.Formatter.format).

```
query_string = "/graph?x={0}".format(str1)
```

Or for your example with the tags:

```
>>> str1 = "Hello World"
>>> query_string = "<a href = /graph?={0}> </a>".format(str1)
>>> query_string
'<a href = /graph?=Hello World> </a>'
```

Comment: That does work on python interactive enviornment. However when you put it in a tag form : <a href = "/graph?x={0}.format(str1) > </a>. It doesnt happen then